# Does it make sense to unit test throwaway code that runs in production?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

One of the primary benefits of unit testing is to provide confidence that when one needs to later alter the code one is not breaking it. However, what benefits does unit testing provide for code that is literally used as one-off throwaway code? This throwaway code is most certainly used in production, but is never actually altered once it's deployed. Does unit testing still make sense in this situation and if so how specifically?

UPDATE: The throwaway code actually is functional-tested before hitting production. Normally, for non-throwaway code it still makes sense to have unit tests despite functional testing occurring. The question here is whether or not it makes sense to also have the unit tests also in the case of throwaway code.

UPDATE 2: The reason why throwaway code is in production in the first place is that this code is literally used for one client, one time only. It's never subject to revision. It is used by a used a single time for a few days. It's very specific to a single client. It's not ever used after that for any other purpose, including the same client. Is there still value in writing unit tests in this case, despite functional tests occurring?

Comment: If you haven't tested that throwaway code, how do you know it's right?

Comment: Why is there throwaway code in production? Why have you scripted something that you're only ever going to run once?

Comment: If **ThrowAway** code was shipped to a customer (which it shouldn't) - it is now **Production** code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests provide benefits in three ways:

1. When code is written test-first, **tests help drive design** and ensure you write testable code. If this is truly throwaway code, then this doesn't matter to you.
2. Tests provide a **safety net for refactoring**. Again, in your situation you may not care.
3. Tests **prove the code does what it is supposed to do**. This DOES apply to throwaway code, especially if the code is written in a test-first manner. I'd much rather write tests as I go, and be confident that I'm shipping something solid to QA, than skip the tests and wait for a QA person to tell me about defects. What if a defect is reported and you have to make a significant change to the code? With automated tests, it's easy to tell if your "fix" broke anything else. Without automated tests you have to repeat the full suite of manual tests, which might be expensive.

To summarize, if the code is truly "throwaway" AND is small or very simple, then you may not get a lot of benefit. If the code is complex, or is relatively large, then tests may be worth something.  (Although, I'd focus on writing high value tests only, targeting features that are hard or costly to test by hand)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how code can be both production code and throwaway code.  The fact that it is being used in production means that it is not throwaway.  What makes you so sure that just because you don't plan on changing it now, someone else might not come around and reuse it or alter it at a later date?

Regardless, there are many benefits to unit testing beyond protection when refactoring.  Unit tests (like all tests) help prove that the code is doing what is supposed to do. You will need to test at some level before you go into production to prove that, and unit tests are an easy way to automate some of that.

The process of writing unit tests often exposes bugs.  It forces you to think about cases that you may not have thought of when you wrote the happy day case.

Comment: Code that could both be production and throw-away could be code that migrates data from one format to another. I've got a situation where I've got to change the encryption of the passwords in the user table. It will be run once per database, and will only ever be run again if the DB is restored from a backup.

Comment: +1: Everything gets tested before it goes into production is the rule.  How long it stays in production doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be willing to bet the time you spent asking the question and coming back to read the answers would have been more than enough time to write a few unit tests. Which was the better use of your time?

It's simple: if you care whether the code is correct or not, you need to test it. Unit test, acceptance test, service test, whatever you call it, it needs to be tested one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

You should be testing this code somehow before putting it into production. Unit testing can be a valuable part here, regardless of the need to do automated regression tests later.

Unit testing can also be used in test-driven development, where you sketch out what the code is supposed to do before actually writing the code. In this scenario, the unit tests help speed up the development process (precisely because you have automated tests at a time when the code still does change).

Comment: +1: Everything gets tested before it goes into production is the rule. How long it stays in production doesn't matter. The idea of "throwaway" is misleading, ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

If I only had a dollar for every piece of "thorwaway" code I ever needed to maintain...